# Commandos-style Line of Sight algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Could you please point me to an article on a Line of Sight RENDERING algorithm? I'm looking for something similar to the one used in the Commandos series of games (by Pyro Studios). The Line of Sight cone/triangle must be rendered (in a top down view) with appropriate shadows caused by obstructions.
Thanks

Comment: Can you describe the function, or should we buy the game to answer?

Comment: Did you ever discover a way to do this?  I'm thinking about making a Commandos style game and this feature needs to be included.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo-code:

```
function get_visible_objects(observer)

  /* get the list of objects inside the cone of vision */
  in_cone = get_the_objects_inside(observer.cone)

  /* sort the objects by proximity to the observer */
  sorted = in_cone.sort_by_distance_to(observer)

  /* visible is the result. start with all the objects in the cone */
  visible = sorted.copy

  /* parse the objects in the cone, from nearest to the observer to farthest away,
     and remove any objects occluded */
  for each object in sorted do
    /* remove any other object that is occluded by object */
    to_remove = []
    for each other in visible do
      if object.occludes(other) then
        to_remove.add(other)
      end
    end
    visible = visible - to_remove
  end

  return visible
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was mainly looking for an algorithm for rendering the LOS region.